# Identify the characters DrawText will underline

Tags: winapi

How can I get the characters which [`DrawText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtext) will underline?

I passed the string `"my rando&m string"`. The `m` gets underlined by `DrawText()`.

I want to fetch the characters which will get underlined. Kindly suggest a solution. Strings can be Japanese as well sometimes.

One way is to do it myself. I don't want to do myself, I want it from the API.

Answer (score 2):

The [SHStripMneumonic function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shstripmneumonicw) (UNICODE or ANSI) can do this.

Notes:

- it removes all the '&' characters from the input string;
- it returns the *last* character with a mnemonic, so for example calling it with "my rando&m stri&ng" will remove all '&' from the string and return 'n';
- you can escape a wanted '&' character if you double it.
- it's documented as "*available through Windows XP and Windows Server 2003. It might be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions of Windows*". For information I tested it on Windows 11 and latest Windows SDK (20348).

Bonus link: [Why is the function SHStripMneumonic misspelled?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080519-00/?p=22273)

Comment: I was going to comment *"There is no public API..."*, and I would have been almost correct, too. Still, I wasn't aware of this one, though I have distant memories of reading the blog article linked to. Either one is totally useful, thanks! (Though you might want to add, that this API isn't *intended" for public use.)